# Git Mirroring created unwanted PR refs on target repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, git-mirror

I have a periodic git synchronization script that runs from bit bucket cloud to our local git repository.

In the nutshell it does the following:

```
git clone --mirror ssh://source.git
git show-ref | cut -d ' ' -f2 | grep 'pull-request' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d
git push --mirror ssh://target.git
```

This sequence cloned the source repo, cleaned all pull request references and pushed to target repository.  It was working without issues for a few months, but today I got the following error:

> remote: You are attempting to update refs that are reserved for
>
> Bitbucket's pull request functionality. Bitbucket manages these refs
>
> automatically, and they may not be updated by users.         remote:
>
> Rejected refs:         remote:    refs/pull-requests/1/from
>
> remote:   refs/pull-requests/1/merge         remote:    ! [remote
>
> rejected] refs/pull-requests/1/from (pre-receive hook declined)   !
>
> [remote rejected] refs/pull-requests/1/merge (pre-receive hook
>
> declined

)

On the target repository, I can see these weird references, but no pull requests in the UI.  I am suspected something became corrupted on the target repository, but I was unable to clear these references with

```
git update-ref -d refs/pull-requests/1/merge
git update-ref -d refs/pull-requests/1/from
git push
```

That operation produces the following error:

> remote: You are attempting to update refs that are reserved for
>
> Bitbucket's pull request functionality. Bitbucket manages these refs
>
> automatically, and they may not be updated by users. remote: Rejected
>
> refs: remote:     refs/pull-requests/1/from remote:
>
> refs/pull-requests/1/merge

I have 2 questions :)

1) What can cause this kind of corruption in the target repository?

2) Is there any way to get rid of these references on the target?